# Fraction calculation

Tags: c++, function

I need to write a program that can calculate fractions using the operator that the user enters. I have different functions to reduce the fractions and find the greatest common denominator (which i'm not sure if i set them up correctly or not), and then I have the function calculate() to find the answer. I have to print out the final answer in fraction form and not decimal.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to return num3 and den3 from calculate() back into the main function. If anyone could help I would very gracious. Thank you.

Here is my code so far:

```
/*Problem: Write a program to manipulate fractions. It allows for the addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division of fractions.
    Inputs:
    Outputs:
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void calculate(int num1, int den1, int& num3, int& den3, int num2, int den2);
void reduce(int& num, int& den);
int gcd(int a, int b);

int main(){
    int num1, num2, den1, den2, add, sub, mult, div;
    int op, calc;
    int num3, den3;

    cout << "Enter the numerator of the first fraction" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the denominator of the first fraction" << endl;
    cin >> den1;
    cout << "Enter the numerator of the second fraction" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Enter the denominator of the second fraction" << endl;
    cin >> den2;
    cout << "Enter a 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, or 4 for division" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    calculate(op, num1, den1, num3, den3, num2, den2);
    cout << "The answer using option: " << op << endl;
    cout << "is " << num3 << " / " << den3 << endl;



    return 0;
}

void calculate(int op, int num1, int den1, int& num3, int& den3, int num2, int den2){
    if(op==1){
        num3 = num1 + num2;
        den3 = den1;
    }
    else if(op==2){
        num3 = num1 - num2;
        den3 = den1;
    }
    else if(op==3){
        num3 = num1 * num2;
        den3 = den1 * den2;
    }
    else if(op==4){
        num3 = num1 * den2;
        den3 = num2 * den1;
    }
}

void reduce(int& num, int& den){
    int reduced;
    reduced = gcd(num, den);
    num = num/reduced;
    den = den/reduced;

}

int gcd(int a, int b){
    int divisor=1, temp;

    while(b!= 0 || b>a){ 
        temp = a % b; 
        a = b; 
        b = temp = divisor; 
    }
    while(a!=0 || a>b){
        temp = b % a;
        b = a;
        a = temp = divisor;
    }

    return divisor;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. You are already doing everything you need, just by assigning new values to `num3` and `den3`. The caller will observe these new values. That's what references are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your function declaration, you left off the first argument, op.

```
void calculate(int num1, int den1, int& num3, int& den3, int num2, int den2);
```

Then you call calculate as you intend,

```
calculate(op, num1, den1, num3, den3, num2, den2);
```

And the function definition has op, so you notice that there is argument mismatch between the declaration, and the definition,

```
void calculate(int op, int num1, int den1, int& num3, int& den3, int num2, int den2)
```

The canonical way to handle rational numbers is declaring a std::pairs, or declaring a class with numerator and denominator.

There is also a flaw in your addition and subtraction code.  You need to consider how to do rational addition/subtraction (see: [Rational addition/Subtraction](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/rational-numbers-operations.html)).  That is fixed below.  You might look closely at gcd to make sure it works correctly.

Also, you might consider using a switch/case statement for deciding operation, and you can convert the numeric input to letter opcode easily.

Here is your code with some flaws fixed and a few other changes,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ratn //rational
{
public:
    int num;  //numerator
    int denom;  //denominator

    friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& stream, const ratn& r);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ratn& r)
{
    stream << r.num << " / " << r.denom;
    return stream;
}

int gcd(int a, int b);
void reduce(ratn& r);
void calculate(int op, ratn a, ratn b, ratn& r );

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int divisor=1, temp;
    while(b!= 0 || b>a){
        temp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = temp = divisor;
    }
    while(a!=0 || a>b){
        temp = b % a;
        b = a;
        a = temp = divisor;
    }
    return divisor;
}

void
reduce(ratn& r )
{
    int reduced;
    reduced = gcd(r.num, r.denom);
    r.num = r.num/reduced;
    r.denom = r.denom/reduced;
}

char operands[8] = { ' ','+','-','*','/','%','^' };
void
calculate(int op, ratn a, ratn b, ratn& r )
{
    switch(op)
    {
    case ('+'):
        r.num = a.num*b.denom + b.num*a.denom;
        r.denom = a.denom*b.denom;
        //reduce(r);
        break;
    case ('-'):
        r.num = a.num*b.denom - b.num*a.denom;
        r.denom = a.denom*b.denom;
        //reduce(r);
        break;
    case ('*'):
        r.num = a.num * b.num;
        r.denom = a.denom * b.denom;
        break;
    case ('/'):
        r.num = a.num * b.denom;
        r.denom = b.num * a.denom;
        break;
    case ('%'):
        //r.num = a.num * b.denom;
        //r.denom = b.num * a.denom;
        break;
    case ('^'):
        //r.num = a.num * b.denom;
        //r.denom = b.num * a.denom;
        break;
    default :
        break;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    int op;
    ratn a, b, r;
    cout << "Enter first fraction, numerator" << endl;
    cin >> a.num;
    cout << "Enter first fraction, denominator" << endl;
    cin >> a.denom;
    cout << "Enter second fraction, numerator" << endl;
    cin >> b.num;
    cout << "Enter second fraction, denominator" << endl;
    cin >> b.denom;
    cout << "Enter operator, 1=addition, 2=subtraction, 3=multiplication, 4=division" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    calculate(operands[op], a, b, r );
    cout << "Answer:" ;
    cout << a << " "<<operands[op]<<" " << b << " = " << r << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed that, but now when i enter these numbers I get this answer using subtraction:                                                  Enter the numerator of the first fraction.
2
Enter the denominator of the first fraction.
4
Enter the numerator of the second fraction.
1
Enter the denominator of the second fraction.
2
Enter a 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, or 4 for division.
2
The answer using option: 2
is 1 / 4
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Consider what you need to do when denom1 and denom2 do not match.  You need to find the smallest number for which both denominators are factors.

Comment: I get this error when trying to compile the fixed code: "1>projects\lab 7_2 good\lab 7_2 good\lab 7_2.cpp(16): error C4716: 'operator<<' : must return a value ". Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed.  operator<<() needs to return stream

Comment: Thank's a lot Mr.Cottrill. I am very grateful.

Comment: the gcd calculation benefits from having a list of prime numbers around, because prime factorization of the denominators is the way to find the gcd (I think your way looks at all integer factors, not just prime factors).  This is one place where having a solid understanding of math (this is basically algebra and light number theory) can be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be nicer to either 1) implement a rational number class, or 2) use std::pairs `<int, int>` for the numerator and denominator. Then you can always return either a rational number in the case of 1, or a pair in the case of 2.

Approach 1 allows you to deal with singularities naturally. You can throw an exception if the denominator is zero.

Just another approach....